# Unable to send real-time notifications saved in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, notifications, signalr, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using the ASP.NET Boilerplate template and trying to get real-time entity-based notifications for specific users. My notifications are published successfully in the `Abp.TenantNotifications` table and the subscriptions are saved successfully in the `Abp.NotificationSubscriptions` table. But I can't get it to be displayed on the client side.

I have integrated my project with SignalR according to [the documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-Integration).

---

**Application Service where I publish the notification**:

```
public async Task PublishCreated(Guid WorkOrderId, long UserId)
{
    var user = await UserManager.GetUserByIdAsync(UserId);

    var workorder = await _workOrderDirectoryRepository.GetAsync(WorkOrderId);

    await _notiticationPublisher.PublishAsync(
        notificationName: "WorkOrder",
        data: new MessageNotificationData("New WO is " + workorder.WorkOrderStatus + " with code " + workorder.WorkOrderCode),
        entityIdentifier: new EntityIdentifier(typeof(WorkOrderDirectory), workorder.Id),
        severity: NotificationSeverity.Success,
        userIds: new[] { user.ToUserIdentifier() }
    );

    await _notificationSubscriptionManager.SubscribeAsync(user.ToUserIdentifier(), "WorkOrder");

    await _backgroundJobManager.EnqueueAsync<WONotificationJob, UserIdentifier>(
        user.ToUserIdentifier(),
        delay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
    );
}
```

---

**Background Job**:

```
public class WONotificationJob : BackgroundJob<UserIdentifier>, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IRealTimeNotifier _realTimeNotifier;
    private readonly IUserNotificationManager _userNotificationManager;

    public WONotificationJob(
        IRealTimeNotifier realTimeNotifier,
        IUserNotificationManager userNotificationManager)
    {
        _realTimeNotifier = realTimeNotifier;
        _userNotificationManager = userNotificationManager;
    }

    [UnitOfWork]
    public override void Execute(UserIdentifier args)
    {
        var notifications = _userNotificationManager.GetUserNotifications(args);
        AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _realTimeNotifier.SendNotificationsAsync(notifications.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

---

**Client-side code**:

```js
function loadWorkOrderDirectories() {
  workOrderDirectoryService.getList().success(function(result) {
    $scope.workOrderDirectories = result.items;
    publishNotifications($scope.workOrderDirectories);
    showUInotifications();
  });
};

loadWorkOrderDirectories();

function publishNotifications(arr) {
  angular.forEach(arr, function(value, key) {
    workOrderDirectoryService.publishCreated(value.id, 2);
  });
};

function showUInotifications() {
  abp.event.on('abp.notifications.received', function(userNotification) {
    abp.notifications.showUiNotifyForUserNotification(userNotification);
    $scope.notis = userNotification;
    if (userNotification.notification.data.type === 'Abp.Notifications.LocalizableMessageNotificationData') {
      var localizedText = abp.localization.localize(
        userNotification.notification.data.message.name,
        userNotification.notification.data.message.sourceName
      );

      $.each(userNotification.notification.data.properties, function(key, value) {
        localizedText = localizedText.replace('{' + key + '}', value);
      });

      alert('New localized notification: ' + localizedText);
    } else if (userNotification.notification.data.type === 'Abp.Notifications.MessageNotificationData') {
      alert('New simple notification: ' + userNotification.notification.data.message);
    }
  });
};
```

---

I'm following this article: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Articles/Developing-MultiTenant-SaaS-ASP.NET-CORE-Angular/index.html

`_realTimeNotifier._onlineClientManager.Clients` is empty. Here's what I got: https://ibb.co/0qmqFfN

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you not using the free Module Zero template?

Comment: Share a repro project that is forked from that template.

Comment: Can you confirm by setting a breakpoint in `Execute` that `_realTimeNotifier._onlineClientManager.Clients[0].Value.UserId` is `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a script tag for `jquery.signalR-2.4.0.js` in **layout.cshtml**.

   ```
   <!--SIGNAL R-->
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.0.js"></script> <!-- Add this -->
   <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
   <script src="~/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.signalr.js"></script>
   ```
2. Move `app.MapSignalR();` to the end of `Configuration`, after authentication, in **Startup.cs**.

   ```
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   {
       // app.MapSignalR(); // Move this...

       // ...

       app.MapSignalR(); // ...here!
   }
   ```